# Set rule-based label then blocking

Tags: qgis, labeling

In QGIS I have a rule-based label. I ALSO want to set the blocking (prevent the label from being overlapped by other features / labels). However, when I try to do this, my rule-based labeling is disappeared.

Is this a bug or a feature?

[image]

Comment: This blocking fonction is for when you dont want label but only want the feature to block other label, you could try to add your layer two time, one for labeling and another one for blocking. Also the blocking and obstacles setting are, as far I as know, to prevent label covering feature not label covering other label (this is controlled by the "show all labels" setting in the labeling engine option)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this within label properties under "Placement":

[image]

Comment: Hmm. That helps, but still not working as expected... Seems blocking is a little finicky.